# Grafana Query to list only the AWS Linked accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I query cloudwatch to show only the linked accounts? I want to display linked accounts as a variable but I'm not sure how to query and list the linked accounts.

[image]

Here is how a query for the graph looks like with linked accounts and currency set.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dimension_values(us-east-1, AWS/Billing, EstimatedCharges, LinkedAccount, {"Currency": "USD"})
```

See doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-templated-queries.html

Comment: Is there a way to filter out tags? I want to see if I can get the cost explore to report costs by tags.